# Destruction ordering of objects after optimization

Tags: assembly, g++, arm, sequence-points

I am trying to time a few function calls in my software to compare different implementations.

To get the desired timings i'm reading the PCCNTR register of my ARM A9 processor at the beginning and the end of the function using a RAII struct.

The problem is that the compiler is not respecting the construction destruction sequence of my objects. *Is this a bug in the compiler or an allowed optimization?*

The compiler is a `arm-none-eabi-g++ (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2012.03-56) 4.6.3`

```
#define GET_TICK(var) \
  asm volatile (\
      "mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0;"\
      : "=r" (var)\
      );

struct tick{
  uint32_t &start;
  uint32_t &end;

  tick(uint32_t& s, uint32_t &e) 
    :start(s)
     , end(e)
  {
    GET_TICK(start);
  }

  ~tick(){
    GET_TICK(end);
  }
};

bool mailbox::send(uint32_t &start, uint32_t &end, uint32_t msg){
  tick t(start, end);
  /* now start should have the current timestamp */
  {
    Spinlocker lock(SPINLOCK_LOCK_REG_0); // RAII mutex locker
    uint32_t cnt = mb_msg_max_count + 1;
    do{
      cnt = count();
      if(cnt >= mb_msg_max_count){
        lock.release();
        lock.get();
      }
    }while(cnt >= mb_msg_max_count);
    *(first_message + cnt) = msg;
    inc_counter(); // free function
    MEM_BARRIER; // #define asm volatile("dsb st;")
    /* spinlock should be destroyed but it is only after t */
  }

  return true;
  /* now end should have the current timestamp */
}
```

Assembler code generated:

```
83000a64 <mailbox::get(unsigned long&, unsigned long&)>:
83000a64: b530        push  {r4, r5, lr}
83000a66: 4604        mov r4, r0
83000a68: 680b        ldr r3, [r1, #0]
83000a6a: b083        sub sp, #12
83000a6c: 4615        mov r5, r2
83000a6e: ee19 2f1d   mrc 15, 0, r2, cr9, cr13, {0}
83000a72: f44f 41d0   mov.w r1, #26624  ; 0x6800
83000a76: 601a        str r2, [r3, #0]
83000a78: a801        add r0, sp, #4
83000a7a: f6c4 210f   movt  r1, #18959  ; 0x4a0f
83000a7e: f000 f871   bl  83000b64 <Spinlocker::Spinlocker(unsigned long volatile*)>
83000a82: 6823        ldr r3, [r4, #0]
83000a84: 681a        ldr r2, [r3, #0]
83000a86: b18a        cbz r2, 83000aac <mailbox::get(unsigned long&, unsigned long&)+0x48>
83000a88: 6819        ldr r1, [r3, #0]
83000a8a: 1e48        subs  r0, r1, #1
83000a8c: 6018        str r0, [r3, #0]
83000a8e: f3bf 8f4e   dsb st
83000a92: 6864        ldr r4, [r4, #4]
83000a94: 1e51        subs  r1, r2, #1
83000a96: f854 4021   ldr.w r4, [r4, r1, lsl #2]
83000a9a: ee19 0f1d   mrc 15, 0, r0, cr9, cr13, {0} <- timer is read before Spinlock is destroyed. Is this allowed?
83000a9e: 6028        str r0, [r5, #0]
83000aa0: a801        add r0, sp, #4
83000aa2: f000 f885   bl  83000bb0 <Spinlocker::~Spinlocker()> <- Shouldn't this be done before issuing the MCR assembly?
83000aa6: 4620        mov r0, r4
83000aa8: b003        add sp, #12
83000aaa: bd30        pop {r4, r5, pc}
83000aac: a801        add r0, sp, #4
83000aae: f000 f86b   bl  83000b88 <Spinlocker::release()>
83000ab2: a801        add r0, sp, #4
83000ab4: f000 f86e   bl  83000b94 <Spinlocker::get()>
83000ab8: 6823        ldr r3, [r4, #0]
83000aba: 681a        ldr r2, [r3, #0]
83000abc: 2a00        cmp r2, #0
83000abe: d1e3        bne.n 83000a88 <mailbox::get(unsigned long&, unsigned long&)+0x24>
83000ac0: e7f4        b.n 83000aac <mailbox::get(unsigned long&, unsigned long&)+0x48>
83000ac2: bf00        nop
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. They should be destroyed in reverse order of creation, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245840/can-you-guarantee-destructor-order-when-objects-are-declared-on-a-stack

Comment: can you access that register via mrc in userspace?

Comment: does it change if you add volatile to "uint32_t &start;
  uint32_t &end;" may be it is an optimization by compiler...

Comment: @auselen This is not running under an OS, this is bare-metal code. So protection is deactivated and i'm able to use MRC.

Comment: @auselen Using volatile does not produce any significantly different access pattern.

Comment: does it complain with anything if you pass -Wall?

Comment: As data points, g++ version 4.4.5 and llvm-g++ version 4.2.1 on x86 and x86-64; and avr-g++ version 4.7.0 all compile this properly, ie. with the tick destroyed last.

Comment: @auselen -Wall does not produce warnings of any kind.

Comment: arm-none-eabi-g++ (Sourcery G++ Lite 2011.03-42) 4.5.2 also compiles this correctly, and so does a non-CodeSourcery build of 4.6.2.

Comment: It looks like a bug.  Have you submitted something to gcc bugzilla?  No one here will know if it is a bug unless they are a gcc developer.  It seems that there is a little more code than you have shown.  You need to give a full preprocessed test case.  If you have/post that, others can verify if it still occurs.  I have gcc 4.7.2.  gcc.gnu.org and sourceware.org are down at this moment.  It is possibly a build issue by code Sourcery; there are many 'input' libraries to the compiler.